# Is setting 'discard' on a partition exposed through LVM sufficient?

Tags: linux, ssd, lvm

From what I understand, I should set `discard` as a mount option for ext4 partitions that are on an SSD.

My `/etc/fstab` currently has this line

`/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root /               ext4   discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro   0       1`

But `/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root` is just a logical volume as part of LVM.

```

```
#sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/xubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                xubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                0JER7E-3HRO-S6lw-oXsL-nk6s-Gy6K-ebIO7F
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xubuntu, 2015-01-16 08:12:44 -0600
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                430.91 GiB
  Current LE             110312
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/xubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                xubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                vWzz8B-lxcY-4Y30-dn4Q-1y6h-2IYx-0fLOru
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xubuntu, 2015-01-16 08:12:44 -0600
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                15.94 GiB
  Current LE             4080
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

```

I have a single partition on my SSD that acts as my physical volume

```

```
#sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               xubuntu-vg
  PV Size               446.89 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              114404
  Free PE               12
  Allocated PE          114392
  PV UUID               5U1Vro-1BGW-NchS-nbPk-bEH0-yCX0-AgaU1O
```

```

Does setting `discard` on the mount option have the desired effect, even though the ext4 filesystem does not use the physical device but instead uses LVM? If not, is there something I can do to address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LVM uses the [Linux device mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper), which passes down discard commands, so setting the `discard` mount option should be sufficient.

To verify that the volume supports discard, run `lsblk --discard`. The `DISC_GRAN` (discard granularity) and `DISC-MAX` (discard max bytes) column should be nonzero for `xubuntu--vg-root`.